# Can i take information from a Bio metric device and calculate attendance using android app. I want to develop such app. Is it possible?

Tags: android, device

Can i take information from a *Bio metric device* and calculate attendance using android app.  I want to develop such app. Is it possible?

Comment: yes sure but for that you need bio metric device or bio metric supported device.

Comment: Thank you @Creative Android.

Comment: Which kind of output am i going to get from that machine, is that a CSV file or excel sheet or something like JSON? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure it is possible

But for that you need to attach bio metric device to phone.

You can find good example and SDK from here http://www.fingeroid.com/

Comment: Thanks @shabbir Dhangot